# GraphQL input type in query response

Tags: input, graphql, schema, apollo, apollo-server

How do I use `QueryResult` to display an input type `GetFoosInput` in query response? I want to display back to the user information he passed.

```
type Bar {
  name: String
}

type Baz {
  filename: String
  length: Int
}

union Foo = Bar | Baz

input GetFoosInput {
  limit: Int
  offset: Int
}

type QueryResult {
  totalCount: Int!
  queryInfo: GetFoosInput!   # unable to do this
  result: [Foo!]
}

type Query {
  getFoos(input: GetFoosInput): QueryResult
}
```

Comment: input type can be used only as arg

Comment: @xadm In that case, should I create identical to input type object type and use it in query response? Seems like a lot of work if you have a lot of input types.

Comment: Just because the types' structure would be the same now doesn't mean they'll always be the same, and output types can have arguments where input types cannot, so they're very different things.

Comment: no (any?) reason to *'display back to the user information he passed'* - type system is not for debug/side reasons